# How to change a specific admin label

Tags: functions, wp-admin, admin-menu

I'm trying to change on the backend from:

Appearance -> Header

To

Appearance -> Logo

But the [Changing Admin Menu Labels](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9211/changing-admin-menu-labels) answer didn't help so far.

Any new tip?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try that with the `gettext` filter in the following manner.

```
function rename_header_to_logo( $translated, $original, $domain ) {

    $strings = array(
        'Header' => 'Logo',
        'Custom Header' => 'Custom Logo',
        'You can upload a custom header image to be shown at the top of your site instead of the default one. On the next screen you will be able to crop the image.' => 'You can upload a custom logo to be shown at the top of your site instead of the default one. On the next screen you will be able to crop the image.'
    );

    if ( isset( $strings[$original] ) && is_admin() ) {
        $translations = &get_translations_for_domain( $domain );
        $translated = $translations->translate( $strings[$original] );
    }

    return $translated;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'rename_header_to_logo', 10, 3 );
```

You might want to check that the text doesn't conflict with another "header" text somewhere else.

Comment: Indeed it conflicts with others "header" text. Unfortunately, gettext is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

When no hook is available, jQuery it...

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wpse_46677_change_menu_item' );

function wpse_46677_change_menu_item()
{
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
                $("#menu-appearance").find("li:contains('Header')").html('<a href="themes.php?page=custom-header">My Text</a');
            });     
        </script>
    <?php
}
```