# Remove and change pages label

Tags: pages, wp-list-pages

[image: Pages label in red]

I want to change the search pages label and remove the numbers of items.

I Want also to modify the number of the visible pages on the listing of the  pages now it's 20 pages.

Solution :

```
function wpd_change_page_labels( $labels ) {

    $labels->search_items  = 'put the new name';
    return $labels;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_labels_page', 'wpd_change_page_labels' );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Admin Menu Labels](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9211/changing-admin-menu-labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To change *Number of items per page* in *Screen Options***, add this code to `functions.php` of your theme:

```
function wpse_modify_screen_option() {
    $number_of_items = 10; // change this to desired value
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->id != 'edit-page' )
        return;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ( $user_id ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'edit_page_per_page', $number_of_items );   
    }
}

function wpse_screen_option() {
    add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'wpse_modify_screen_option' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_screen_option' );
```

This will change *Number of items per page* in *Screen Options* for all users. If you want to do it for selected users only, replace the line:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'edit_page_per_page', $number_of_items );
```

with

```
$users = array( id1,...,idn, ); // replace id1 to idn with user ids
if ( in_array( $user_id, $users ) )
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'edit_page_per_page', $number_of_items );
```

**To change the search pages label and remove the numbers of items**, make and add the following script ( wpse_search_button.js ) to the root of your theme:

```
// JavaScript Document
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $('.displaying-num').css( 'display', 'none' );
    $('#search-submit').val( 'Look for Pages' );
});
```

Now add this to `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_load_admin_js() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $typenow == 'page' ) {
        wp_register_script( 'wpse-search-button-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/wpse_search_button.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse-search-button-js' );   
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_load_admin_js' );
```

This will hide number of items and change 'Search Pages' button label to 'Look for Pages'.