# How to change name "Profile"

Tags: profiles

I want to change the name "Profile" to something else.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Admin Menu Labels](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9211/changing-admin-menu-labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following. Add to your `functions.php`

```
function admin_profile_menu()
{
    remove_menu_page('profile.php');
    add_menu_page(
        "NEWLABEL",
        "NEWLABEL",
        "",
        "profile.php",
        "",
        "dashicons-admin-users",
        "40"
    );

}
add_action('admin_menu', 'admin_profile_menu');
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It removes all names from the left bar and messed up entire wordpress admin panel.

Comment: @Adelita Updated.