# order of date column in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, columns

I have a custom post type and trying to set custom columns, the date column is there by default, and it appears right after the title. Do I have to unset the date first and then re-apply it, or is there a more elegant way of achieving this:

```
function custom_columns($columns) {
    unset( $columns['date'] );

    $columns = array_merge($columns, array(
        'title'     => 'Alert Title',
        'region'    => 'Region',
        'date'      => 'Date',
        ) 
    );

    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: I'd say there's nothing wrong with this approach... What problem do you have with it, sortable columns?

Comment: I don't have a problem with it, I was just wondering if there was a better way of doing it. Seems 'hacky' to be unsetting it just to set it in a different spot

Comment: It's just array manipulation, I've done [hackier things](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78640/12615) ;)

Comment: lol, k. I thought maybe there was a `menu_position` type of thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the only thing there is to do: *array manipulation*.

The filter `manage_edit-CPT_columns` is fired in [**`class-wp-list-table.php`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L90):

```
add_filter( "manage_{$this->screen->id}_columns", array( &$this, 'get_columns' ), 0 );
```

Which in turn dispatches the function `get_columns()` in the sub-class [**`class-wp-posts-list-table.php`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L249).

And, inside it, one filter for taxonomies, and others for *post/page/cpt* columns.
And all of them dealing with array elements.
Maybe a *one line solution* exists with some PHP function, but two lines is valid code too.