# Add a Separator to the Admin Menu?

Tags: admin, admin-menu

Does anyone know how to add an admin menu separator? I found [this](http://lab.yukei.net/wp-code/nav.html?wp-admin/menu.php.source.html) but it did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: In case anyone's still searching for the answer to this, [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) can handle the job.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way to get what you want.

### Background

WordPress stores admin menu sections in a global array called `$menu`. To add a separator you add an element to the `$menu` array using an index that is between the indexes of the options that you want to separate.

### Using the `add_admin_menu_separator()` function

So I've written a function to encapsulate the logic for this I called `add_admin_menu_separator()`. You'll need to pick an array index number that is higher than the option *after which* you want to add a separator, and then call the function `add_admin_menu_separator()` passing said index as your parameter.

For example:

```
add_admin_menu_separator(37);
```

### The `add_admin_menu_separator()` function itself

Here's the definition of the function `add_admin_menu_separator()` which you can copy into your theme's `functions.php` file. Yes it is arcane but then so is the code that creates and uses the global `$menu` array. *(Plans are to eventually deprecate it, thankfully, but that'll probably be a few years.)*

```
function add_admin_menu_separator($position) {
  global $menu;
  $index = 0;
  foreach($menu as $offset => $section) {
    if (substr($section[2],0,9)=='separator')
      $index++;
    if ($offset>=$position) {
      $menu[$position] = array('','read',"separator{$index}",'','wp-menu-separator');
      break;
    }
  }
  ksort( $menu );
}
```

### Finding the index into `$menu` that you need

To figure out what index number you need you can do a `var_dump()` of `$GLOBALS['menu']` from within an `admin_init` hook. Here's a bit of code you can drop into your theme's `functions.php` file temporarily to see what the values are. This will only work when requesting a URL starting with `/wp-admin/` *(but be sure to do with with FTP and not the built in theme editor or you'll loose access to your site, at least until you get FTP access to your theme's `functions.php` file!)*:

```
add_action('admin_init','dump_admin_menu');
function dump_admin_menu() {
  if (is_admin()) {
    header('Content-Type:text/plain');
    var_dump($GLOBALS['menu']);
    exit;
  }
}
```

### See Also:

BTW, you might find these links useful in general for working with admin menus:

- [**Changing the Order of Admin Menu Sections**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/changing-the-order-of-admin-menu-sections/1222#1222)
- [**Latest: `wp-admin-menu-classes.php`**](https://gist.github.com/792b7aa5b695d1092520)

Although my admin menu classes don't currently offer an easy way to add separators I think I'll now add that when I have time.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I checked all night studying global var menu, but I didn't managed to add a separator,it is now much clearer to me how menus works in wp.

Comment: Hi *@user1147*: Yes, they are very hard to figure out. When I first had to it took me quite a lot of time, and I still struggle with them. Hence why I wrote those functions, so I can do it the easy way from now on! Anyway, glad my answer helped.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel This method isn't working for me with Wordpress 3.3.1.

Comment: @JimGeurts - it's not working for me either :/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: I just tested it and it does "work" in 4.5, but WordPress decided to get rid of the lines do they just do not appear anymore.  I think the solution if to add CSS but for the life of me I cannot figure out what CSS to add since I am a backend dev and suck at CSS.  Maybe someone else can suggest?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel that bug has been fixed now. The suggested code would set the separator in the specified index, but if we add some random noise to the index it will not be replaced — because `37.4345` is not `37` :)

Comment: Query Monitor is showing a PHP error via AJAX in the `add_admin_menu_separator` function, and it looks like it's because `$menu` doesn't exist for REST API requests. Wrapping everything after the `global $menu` in a `if (!empty($menu)) { }` seems to take care of it.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy as:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_sep' );
function add_sep() {

    if ( ! is_admin() )
        return false;

    global $menu;
    $sep = $menu[4]; // that's the default separator
    $pos = 6; // change it for the desired position
    $menu = array_merge(
        array_slice( $menu, 0, $pos ),
        array( $sep ),
        array_slice( $menu, $pos + 1, -1)
    );
    $menu[ $pos - 1 ][4] .= ' menu-top-last';
    $menu[ $pos + 1 ][4] .= ' menu-top-first';

}
```

Note: The default separator position (`$menu[4]`) can be different depending of which configuration you (or your plugins) have done before this hook.

Of course, you can also tweak the `menu-top-first` and `menu-top-last` classes introspection.

Answer (score 3):

Had some issues with separators not being added, it was due to the way wordpress removes duplicate separators. Adding `ksort($menu);` to the bottom of the function corrected the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add this in functions.php

```
add_action('admin_menu', function () {   
  global $menu;
  $menu[49] = ['', 'read', '', '', 'wp-menu-separator'];
});
```

Where 49 is separator position, You have to remember that separator position can replace your menu element if it has the same position.

Answer (score 1):

This builds on MastaBaba's answer, but does not replace anything at the position you specify - it just adds the separator afterwards.

Also uses an anonymous function so it's only compatible with PHP version 5.3 and above.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function () {
    $position = 29;
    global $menu;
    $separator = [
        0 => '',
        1 => 'read',
        2 => 'separator' . $position,
        3 => '',
        4 => 'wp-menu-separator'
    ];
    if (isset($menu[$position])) {
        $menu = array_splice($menu, $position, 0, $separator);
    } else {
        $menu[$position] = $separator;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to determine what you're trying to do, but I think you're looking to add a top-level entry in the WordPress admin menu.

See [this documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus#Top-Level_Menus) in the WordPress Codex.

In short, you're looking for usage of the `add_menu_page()` function, which takes a number of arguments and displays an additional item in the administrative menu as a sibling of "Dashboard", "Posts", "Media", etc.

Hope I got it right. :-)

Comment: I'm just trying to add an admin menu seprator. Before posting the question I tried to use `add_menu_page()`.

Comment: Looks like MikeSchinkel got you pretty well covered. Sorry about the misunderstanding. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The below ads an action to Wordpress that is run when the admin menu is rendered. The admin menu is an array and all you're doing, here, is adding an array element that defines a separator, in the position you specify.

From [here](https://tommcfarlin.com/add-a-separator-to-the-wordpress-menu/):

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'set_admin_menu_separator' );
function set_admin_menu_separator() {
$position = 79;
global $menu;
$menu[$position] = array(
0   =>  '',
1   =>  'read',
2   =>  'separator' . $position,
3   =>  '',
4   =>  'wp-menu-separator'
);
}
```

Note that, though this rather resembles the currently accepted answer, the currently accepted answer did not work for me (and, judging from the comments, for several others).

Comment: There is no difference to the existing, accepted answer, except that you don't give any explanation. Please read [answer].

Comment: @toscho: Well, this works for me and the accepted answer does not.