# Adding admin menu seperators around CPT's

Tags: custom-post-types

I thought this might have been something I could add to the CPT's,  but couldnt see a straight forward answer on how to do it.

I currently have 5 custom post types.  As you can imagine having that many custom post types,  along with the normal wordpress admin items ( Plus any plugin menus ) it can get quite bulky and unattractive.

So id like to add a separator above the first CPT menu and below the last CPT item.

Currently all of the CPT's are using this :

```
'menu_position' => 5,
```

5 may not be their final resting place,  but would like to know if there is a simple way of adding a separator above or below a certain CPT ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2666/add-a-separator-to-the-admin-menu

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84086/add-separator-to-admin-submenu

Comment: Perfect thank you,  that was much clearer than any other post I had read :)