# how to change/remove/hide menu under installed plugins

Tags: plugins, menus

Recently I install one plugin. After installing the "bookingwizz" plugin, the menu added in menu. Under bookingwizz I now have some submenu as well. Now I don't need all those menu items, but want to keep some and change some name and remove some. So how would I do that? I tried to search in that plugins file and also in database, but never found anything. Here's a screenshot of the menu

> [image]

Comment: Pleas use proper lower-/upper case characters. This is no chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution using Codes

To hide a menu from a plugin menu, you need to look for the plugin hook. And after finding the hook, [`remove_submenu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page) will help you to achieve the desired task done. Using the hook and the `remove_submenu_page()`, you can remove the submenu exactly from that plugin.

For a complete understanding of the whole, refer to the article like:

> [**The Complete Guide To The WordPress Settings API** - Tom McFarlin](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-1/)

Then to know how to unset something you may refer to [this WPSE thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/make-sub-menu-items-a-main-link-in-the-admin-menu-using-fuctions-php/9377#9377).

#### Easy Solution

But for an easy solution, you can use **Adminize**, a free WordPress plugin that will assist you to show/hide certain menu and/or services by the admin roles:

> [**Adminize** - WordPress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/)