# Grouping of CPTs and taxonomies into menu groups in admin

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-admin

I have a group of custom post types such as "CPT A", "CPT B" and "CPT C".  I display the admin page for each of these as subpages under a common Admin page.

```
add_menu_page('Console',
    'Console',
    'plugin_console',
    'plugin',
    array ( $this, 'page_main' ),
    "http://example.com/favicon.ico",
    6
    );
```

There are also custom taxonomies for the CPTs, and some of them are shared.

What I'm to do is, in the admin pane add submenu page off the main one that links to the taxonomies in edit-tags.php.

```
add_submenu_page('plugin',
    'Taxonomy',
    'Taxonomy',
    'manage_options',
    'plugin-taxonomy',
    array( $this, 'page_taxonomy' )
    );
```

The problem I encounter is that the list table doesn't fill.  Any suggestions on a good/better approach are most welcome.

Just as a follow up, I want a menu that looks something like:

```
-Console
--CPT A
--CPT B
--CPT C
--Taxonomy 1
--Taxonomy 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could manipulate the global `$menu` and `$submenu` inside the `admin_menu` hook. But it's easier to let [Mike Schinkel's WP Admin Menu Classes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1222/12615) take care of it.

```
require_once('inc/wp-admin-menu-classes.php');

add_action( 'admin_menu', function()
{
    $plugin_page = 'wpse_114343'; 
    add_menu_page(
        'Console',
        'Console',
        'edit_pages',
        $plugin_page,
        function() {},
        "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico",
        6
    );
    // Move the CPT Movie and remove original
    $cpt = "edit.php?post_type=movie";
    copy_admin_menu_item( $plugin_page,$cpt );
    remove_admin_menu_section( $cpt );

    // Move the CPT Page and remove original
    $cpt2 = "edit.php?post_type=page";
    copy_admin_menu_item( $plugin_page, $cpt2 );
    remove_admin_menu_section( $cpt2 );

    // Move Posts Category and Tags and remove originals
    $cat = "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category";
    $tag = "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag";
    $tax_menu = 'edit.php';
    copy_admin_menu_item( $plugin_page, $tax_menu, $cat );
    copy_admin_menu_item( $plugin_page, $tax_menu, $tag );
    remove_admin_menu_item( $tax_menu, $cat );
    remove_admin_menu_item( $tax_menu, $tag );
});
```

[image: manipulated wp-admin menu and sub-menu]