# Issue on CPT Custom Menu Position in WP

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I have Two CPT as "Dress" and "Casual" and I would like to position them close to each other exactly after the "Dashboard" in the Menu.

I have this code in my custom post type for both:

```
'menu_position'       => 2
```

how ever the result is displaying as:

[image]

the "Post" positions after the "Dress"! can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can keep all CPT after each other before the "Post".(I have 5 Custom Post Type)

Thanks

Comment: Try 'menu_position'       => 2 and 'menu_position'       => 3

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for reply but same thing happen!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of Custom Post Types, you may need to change the menuposition with a little trick.

Keep in Mind, WordPress has some built in:

```
2 Dashboard
4 Separator
5 Posts
10 Media
15 Links
20 Pages
25 Comments
59 Separator
60 Appearance
65 Plugins
70 Users
75 Tools
80 Settings
99 Separator
```

Your first CPT is assigned `menu_position` 2, and it is placed just after the Dashboard. As Number 2 (Dashboard), 3 (CPT), 4 (Seperator) and 5 (Posts) are taken, WordPress assigns the next free Number as 6 (behind the Posts).

Your solutions would either be Assigning the Custom Post Types as a Group between Comments and the 59-Seperator (Numbers 26 to 58), or reassigning the Menupositions of the built in Post Types, as well as messing around with the new ones, excellently described by *@MikeSchinkel* based on the work of *@EAmann* [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/changing-the-order-of-admin-menu-sections)